ASP.NET Core microservice Clean Architecture need to process 2 documents either both or none
I need suggestions on an approach to ensure either processing of both documents is successful, and we inform UI that both were processed successfully - or we inform UI that processing failed. Both documents will be uploaded to AWS S3 bucket.
